# How to check if wireless interface is internal or external

Tags: scripts

I am currently working on a script where i need to check if wireless interface is external or internal. Supoose i have the following output for iwconfig:

```
wlp2s0    unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

wlx00e1b010ea1f  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

i know that wlp2s0 is my internal wireless card and wlx00e1b010ea1f is my external wireless adapter.
so the script should print the following result:

```
wlp2s0 -> Internal
wlx00e1b010ea1f -> External
```

PS:
i was able to determine such info using the following command:

```
>nmcli -f GENERAL,WIFI-PROPERTIES dev show wlx00e02d3c613e | grep usb
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlx00e02d3c613e
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
```

by grepping usb, if there was any result, then i know that the interface is external.

BUT the problem was this command didnt work when NetworkManager WAS DOWN.

Comment: Read `man lspci lsusb lshw`. They should provide enough information.

Answer (score 1):

wlp means, roughly, **W**ire**L**ess **P**ci, in other words, an internal device. The 2s0 part refers to the PCI bus to which the device is attached.

wlx means, roughly, **W**ire**L**ess e**X**ternal. The 00e1b010ea1f part is the MAC address of the device.

Reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html